# Realm Browser Crashes

Tags: android, realm

В Realm Browser при открытии автоматически сгенерированной Demo Database - Browser рушится. Не подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

```
Process:         Realm Browser [9599]
Path:            /Applications/Realm Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/RealmBrowser
Identifier:      io.realm.realmbrowser
Version:         2.1.2 (85)
App Item ID:     1007457278
App External ID: 819948401
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [187]
Responsible:     Realm Browser [9599]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2017-01-18 22:08:24.589 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  AC53167C-0CF2-C159-A4B4-FCA929016D33

Sleep/Wake UUID: 3E1A98F5-95FB-4D9A-97BA-F79215DFAAEA

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Assertion failed: (tokenCount < maxCountIncludingZeroTerminator - 1),    function CUIRenditionKeySetValueForAttribute, file  /SourceCache/CoreUI/CoreUI- 231.1/CoreTheme/ThemeStorage/CUIThemeRendition.m, line 136.


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
...
```

Comment: Это десктопное приложение под OS X. Рекомендую задать вопрос в http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=realm. Они (разработчики Realm) мониторят этот тэг в англоязычной версии сайта. Вопрос нужно задавать, естественно на английском языке.

Comment: Да, спасибо, думала написать туда (скорее даже сюда https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues ) если тут не получится решить. Были сомнения в своих прямых руках или ПО. Отправляюсь туда. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Конкретно под realm browser issue пишется сюда: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues (выше ссылка в скобках не совсем корректна)

Answer (score 0):

Фиксится обновлением Realm Browser.